# Библиотека для клавиш

Tags: c, клавиатура, windows-7

Хочу сделать игру с псевдографикой, но не знаю, какая библиотека нужна для считывания нажатия на клавишу :(
Вот часть кода

```
    char hp1 = 219;  //Первая "текстурка" для обзначения "жизней"
    char hp2 = 177;  //Вторая "текстурка" для обзначения "жизней"(чтобы не сливалось)
    while (TRUE)     
    {
        Sleep(19);
        printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", hp1,hp2,hp1,hp2,hp1,hp2,hp1,hp2,hp1,hp2,hp1);
        if(Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Key.F))
        {
            while (TRUE)
            {
        Sleep(19);
        printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", hp1,hp2,hp1,hp2,hp1,hp2,hp1,hp2,hp1,hp2);      
            }
        }   


    }//В первом "куске" кода выводится изначальное кол-во "жизней". Во втором
по нажатии клавиши их кол-во уменьшаем.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Windows.h - [Более подробнее тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_inputdev/)